Utilising Graph Api in SharePoint Framework Setup
We have SPFX solutions utilising Graph Api to retrieve users information. The solutions are working as expected. I am trying to identify the setup configured for this App.
The only think can I find the Graph Api access is can be displayed in  API access under SharePoint Central admin. The access permission is given for Microsoft.Graph is User.ReadBasic.All.
My questions are does the SPFX graph Api, require App registration and access configured in Azure AD?. Because I could not find any App registration associated with app that utilising the Graph Api.
Does it require Service Principal setup and scope in Azure AD?
I also read this documentation and nothing mention about setting up in App registration and User principal required permission setup and scope in Azure AD.
https://purple.telstra.com/blog/steps-to-use-microsoft-graph-api-with-sharepoint-framework

SPFx use OAuth implicit flow for authorization purpose
Connect to Azure AD-secured APIs in SharePoint Framework solutions
Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow
In every Azure subscription asscoiated with SharePoint online tenant, Entra App(previously known as Azure AD app) with name

SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal

exists under Enterprise Applications. When the admin approves SPFx Web API permission requests(ex. Microsoft.Graph-User.ReadBasic.All) those get added in this Entra app under permission section and with the help of Implicit flow OAuth, SPFx authorize and provide the response.
